# malloc() call in function - segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm a C-beginner and have just tried to implement a makeRandomTree()-function to randomly create a binary tree.

Although compilation was successful sometimes (not always!) the program exits with error "Segmentation fault: 11" at runtime. I presume the error is located in makeRandomNode()-function, where the dynamic memory allocation with malloc() is situated. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find the error yet.

I hope someone could help me =)

Here's the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_NODES 10
#define RANDOM_NUMBER_MAX 99

struct node {
    int nodeValue;
    struct node *parentNode;
    struct node *leftChild;
    struct node *rightChild;
};

typedef struct node node;

node* makeRandomNode(unsigned int *randomSeed) {
    //random number in the range [0;RANDOM_NUMBER_MAX]
    int random = (rand_r(randomSeed) % (RANDOM_NUMBER_MAX + 1));

    node *newNode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode->nodeValue = random;
    newNode->parentNode = NULL;
    newNode->leftChild = NULL;
    newNode->rightChild = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

void insertNode(node *root, node *newNode) {
    if (newNode->nodeValue <= root->nodeValue) {
        if (root->leftChild == NULL) {
            root->leftChild = newNode;
            newNode->parentNode = root;
        }
        else {
            insertNode(root->leftChild, newNode);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (root->rightChild == NULL) {
            root->rightChild = newNode;
            newNode->parentNode = root;
        }
        else {
            insertNode(root->rightChild, newNode);
        }
    }
}

node* makeRandomTree(int numberOfNodes) {
    int i;
    unsigned int randomSeed;
    node *root;
    node *newNode;

    randomSeed = time(NULL);
    root = makeRandomNode(&randomSeed);

    for (i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        newNode = makeRandomNode(&randomSeed);  
        insertNode(root, newNode);
    }

    return root;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    node *tree = makeRandomTree(NUMBER_OF_NODES);

    printf("A random-binary-tree with %i nodes was created successfully!!!\n", NUMBER_OF_NODES);
    printf("'NodeValue' of root is %i\n", tree->nodeValue);
    printf("'NodeValue' of left child of root is %i\n", tree->leftChild->nodeValue);
    printf("'NodeValue' of right child of root is %i\n", tree->rightChild->nodeValue);
    printf("etc.\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also, learn to use a debugger like `gdb` and step through your code to pinpoint the errorneous instruction.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. When you run in a debugger it will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine (and walk up) the function call stack, and let you examine the values of involved variables. At the very least please edit your question to show us where the crash actually happens in *your* code.

Comment: @PelZa I wouldn't focus on makeRandomTree(), with _random_ numbers you may have _unexpected_ sequences...

Comment: All of the above + _Please don't cast the return of `malloc` & co_

Comment: If your question is 'how do you debug a segmentation fault", why post all that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tree handling code looks ok in general, but this could be a problem:

```
printf("'NodeValue' of left child of root is %i\n", tree->leftChild->nodeValue);
printf("'NodeValue' of right child of root is %i\n", tree->rightChild->nodeValue);
```

If the tree by chance does not have a left or right child, you try to dereference a `NULL`-pointer.
Guard it by `if (tree->leftChild) ...`

Comment: Yep, confirmed with a Valgrind run-through. Now quick, what is the chance of all nine child node valuess being either smaller or bigger than the root value. `;)`

Comment: Repost to math.stackexchange.com ;)